# How to show Cauchy continuity implies continuity

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

How to show that every cauchy continuous function between metric spaces are continuous?

I am absolutely clueless. I tried using sequencial criterion of continuity but couldn’t find a way out.

Comment: It would be helpful if you started by explaining what definitions you are working with, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: I am trying to use sequencial criterion of continuity

Comment: What are the definitions you are working with?  When you say that you "tried using sequential criterion of continuity," what does that mean?  What did you actually try to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the sequential continuity is a good idea, but I think it just needs a subtle little trick. Instead of mapping a convergent sequence $x_1, x_2, \ldots \to x$ under $f$, try mapping the modified sequence,
$$x_1, x, x_2, x, x_3, x, \ldots$$
Convince yourself that this sequence converges to $x$ and hence is Cauchy. When you map it under $f$, you'll get a sequence
$$f(x_1), f(x), f(x_2), f(x), f(x_3), f(x), \ldots$$
By Cauchy continuity, this is Cauchy. Now, you can take a constant subsequence of $f(x)$, which means that the sequence converges to $f(x)$ (you do not need completeness to show this). Then, the subsequence
$$f(x_1), f(x_2), f(x_3), \ldots$$
converges to $f(x)$ as well.

Comment: That is simply superb

Comment: That's an amazing proof. +1

Answer (score 2):

We have two notions of continuity running around.  First, the usual notion of continuity can be expressed using our old friends $\varepsilon$ and $\delta$:

> Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be two metric spaces, and let $f : X\to Y$.  We say that $f$ is **continuous** if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $d_{X}(x_1, x_2) < \delta$ implies that $d_{Y}(f(x_1),f(x_2)) < \varepsilon$.

Perhaps less familiar here is the notion of Cauchy continuity, which basically says that Cauchy sequences go to Cauchy sequences:

> Let $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$ be two metric spaces, and let $f : X\to Y$.  If $\{ f(x_j) \}$ is Cauchy in $Y$ for any Cauchy sequence $\{ x_j \}$ in $X$, we say that $f$ is **Cauchy continuous**.

The goal is to prove that Cauchy continuity is stronger than the usual notion of continuity, i.e. Cauchy continuous implies continuous.  A possible proof goes as follows:

*Proof:*  Suppose that $f : X \to Y$ is Cauchy continuous.  Suppose for contradiction that $f$ is *not* continuous.  Negating the definition of continuity, this implies that there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $\delta > 0$ we can find $x_1,x_2\in X$ such that $d_X(x_1,x_2) < \delta$, but $d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2)) > \varepsilon$.

Fix some $x\in X$.  By the above, for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, we can find some $x_n \in X$ such that
$$ d_X(x, x_n) < \frac{1}{n}
\qquad\text{but}\qquad
d_Y(f(x),f(x_n)) > \varepsilon. $$
The first condition implies that $x_n \to x$, which further implies that the sequence $\{x_j\}$ is convergent (and therefore Cauchy) in $X$.  But then $\{ f(x_j) \}$ is Cauchy in $Y$.

Now consider the sequence $\{\hat{x}_j\}$, defined by
$$ \hat{x}_j = 
\begin{cases}
x_k & \text{if $j = 2k$, and} \\
x & \text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$
Observe that $\{\hat{x}_j\}$ is Cauchy and converges to $x$. Moreover, since $f$ is Cauchy continuous, we know that $\{f(\hat{x}_j)\}$ is Cauchy.  From this, we know that we can make $d_Y(f(\hat{x}_m), f(\hat{x}_n))$ small by choosing $m$ and $n$ sufficiently large.  By choosing $m$ even and $n$ odd, we obtain
$$ d_Y(f(\hat{x}_m), f(\hat{x}_n)) = d_Y(f(x_{m/2}), f(x)), $$
which implies that $f(x_{m/2}) \to f(x)$.  That is, $f(x_n) \to f(x)$.  This contradicts the construction of $\{x\}_j$ and completes the proof.

Comment: Suppose $\{f(x_j)\}$ is Cauchy in $Y$. How the uniqueness of limits implies that $f(x_j)\to f(x)$?

Comment: If $\{f(x_j)\}$ is cauchy, then for all $\epsilon>0$, there is an $N\in\mathbb N$ such that for all $m,n\ge N$, $d(f(x_m),f(x_n))<\epsilon$. Now
$$d(f(x_n),f(x))\le d(f(x_n),f(x_m))+d(f(x_m),f(x))$$

or

$$d(f(x_n),f(x))-d(f(x_m),f(x))\le d(f(x_n),f(x_m))<\epsilon$$

which implies that $d(f(x_n),f(x))=d(f(x_m),f(x))$, but we don't know that $\{f(x_j)\}$ is convergent to conclude that $\{f(x_j)\}\to f(x)$ by the uniqueness of limits?

Comment: @user486600 Sorry, I really did skip quite a few steps there---they seemed obvious to me, but, in retrospect, I don't know why.  My thought was, essentially, the same as Theo Bendit's:  consider $\{x_1, x, x_2, x, x_3, \dotsc\}$, which is also Cauchy.  It's image is Cauchy, and it is very easy to see that its image converges to $x$.  But if a sequence converges, then all of it subsequences converge to the same unique limit, which gets us convergence of the original sequence.

Comment: OK, I thought that you want to use another method.

Comment: If $f$ is continuous then it is continuous at every point $x\in X$ so

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta>0,\forall y\in X,d(x,y)<\delta\implies d(f(x),f(y))<\epsilon$$

So if $f$ is not continuous then it is non-continuous in some point like $x$, so

$$\exists\epsilon>0,\forall\delta>0,\exists y\in X,d(x,y)<\delta\implies d(f(x),f(y))>\epsilon$$

Thus, I think that in your proof $x$ should be a noncontinuity point not just some point. Am I wrong?

Comment: OK, You are right and I think that you've used the fact that if $f$ is not continuous then it is not uniformly continuous.